# Тесты Codeception для CakePHP 2

Tags: php, cakephp, codeception

Есть ли модуль Codeception для `CakePHP 2.*`? Для 3-его находил.
Установил Codeception в `/var/www`. В корне проекта сделал `../vendor/bin/codecept` `bootstrap` и `../vendor/bin/codecept build`. Папка `tests` появилась. В принципе, простые тесты проходят. Но, когда, допустим, надо сделать тест на "зайти на страницу товара -> положить в корзину -> перейти в корзину (до этого момента все нормально) и начать вводить в филды данные для оформления заказа Codeception перестает видеть необходимые поля (содержимое header видит, а содержимое body: формы и т.д. уже нет) (подозреваю, что с этого момента и нужен модуль для CakePHP 2.*)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Расширения на `CakePHP 2.*` у `Codeception` нет. 
Но есть `Selenium` и модуль `DB`. Можно написать интеграционные тесты.